# SpringSecurity redirects me back to login.jsp

Tags: jsp, spring-security

when i submit loginForm,it response with `location:login.jsp`

so it always redirects me back  to login.jsp 

but i'm sure that my username and password are correct

and i rewrite `UserDetailsService` ,i checked it doesn't take this step

so,where is the problem?

thx for help!

[response info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRJPT.png)

config file:

```
<http pattern="/login_sso.jsp" security="none"></http>
<http pattern="/css/**" security="none"></http>
<http pattern="/fonts/**" security="none"></http>
<http pattern="/images/**" security="none"></http>
<http pattern="/js/**" security="none"></http>
<http pattern="/lib/**" security="none"></http>
<http pattern="/plugins/**" security="none"></http>
<http use-expressions="false">
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <form-login login-page="/login_sso.jsp" default-target-url="/index.html" login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
        authentication-failure-url="/login_sso.jsp" always-use-default-target="true"/>  
    <csrf disabled="true"/>
    <headers>
        <frame-options policy="SAMEORIGIN"/>
    </headers>
    <logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/login_sso.jsp"/>
</http>
```

jsp:

```
<form id="loginForm" name="loginForm" action="/modify/j_spring_security_check" method="post" >
            <input type="text" id="username" name="name"  />
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" />
            <input value="login" style="width:100%;" type="button" onclick="document:loginForm.submit()">
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="loginForm" name="loginForm" action="/modify/j_spring_security_check" method="post" >
```

The action url is `/modify/j_spring_security_check`, but the processing url is `/j_spring_security_check`

```
<form-login login-page="/login_sso.jsp" default-target-url="/index.html" login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
        authentication-failure-url="/login_sso.jsp" always-use-default-target="true"/>  
    <csrf disabled="true"/>
```

Try to change them to same.

Answer (score 0):

i check the login-processing-url again 

when i set `login-processing-url="login"`(or don't set login-processing-url)

i can login with `action="/login"`, `post url=http://localhost:8080/login`

but when i deploy it at tomcat 7.0

i set `login-processing-url="login"` and `action="/login`

post url change to `http://localhost:8080/project/login`,response is 404

at last,`login-processing-url="/project/login"`  ,  `action="/project/project/login"` 
 
login successfully!